# How to do something each the time the "first of type" is found?

Tags: php, sql

While in a loop, I want to be able to do something **each time** it is the **first time** there is a new day.

For example:

```
<div>31/12/1999</div>
<div>31/12/1999</div>
<div>1/01/2000</div> //do something to this row
<div>1/01/2000</div>
<div>1/01/2000</div>
<div>2/01/2000</div> //do something to this row
<div>2/01/2000</div>
```

I want something like this, but I can't figure it out.

```
while($date = mysql_fetch_array($dates)){

    if($current_date != $previous_date){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: `$date = '';

while($date = mysql_fetch_array($dates)){
   if($date !==''){
  if($current_date !== $date){
         //do stuff

         $date = $current_date;
     }
   }else{

      $date = $current_date;
   }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple, php reads from the top to the bottom so you can just take advantage of that.

```
//Setting the variable so we don't get UNDEFINED INDEX on the first run
$previous_date = ''; 
while($date = mysql_fetch_array($dates)){
    $current_date = $date;
    if($current_date != $previous_date){
        //do stuff
    }
    $previous_date = $current_date;
}
```

This way the `$previous_date` will contain the last value while being overwritten with the new date to check once the comparison has been made.

Comment: That's awesome, I thought it might be something like that but couldn't figure it out. What can I do about the undefined index for the first loop of $previous_date?

Comment: @Maurice I'm still waking up and noticed a flaw in my code, give me a sec. - There, all solved :)

Comment: @Maurice The code  should be working now, sorry for the sloppy start :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time the date appears for the first time, we can store it in a variable called $unique_dates.

Try this:

```
$unique_dates = [];
$dates = mysql_fetch_array($dates);
//$dates = ["31/12/1999", "31/12/1999", "1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", "1/01/2000", "2/01/2000", "2/01/2000"];
foreach($dates as $k => $date) {
    if (!in_array($date, $unique_dates)) {
        $unique_dates[] = $date;
        echo $date." has appeared for the first time in ".$k." index";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
```